# UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type -Quarkus

Tags: java, rest, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm new to Quarkus and I'm getting the following error.I just want to create a end point to get Device object with the any type of parameter. I'm unable to identify the error behind this.

Error :

```
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type ai.govi.telemetry.service.DeviceResourceService and qualifiers [@Default]
        - java member: ai.govi.telemetry.web.DeviceResource():deviceResourceService
        - declared on CLASS bean [types=[java.lang.Object, ai.govi.telemetry.web.DeviceResource], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=ai.govi.telemetry.web.DeviceResource]
```

This is my DeviceResourceService class

```
package ai.govi.telemetry.service;

import ai.govi.telemetry.domain.Device;
import ai.govi.telemetry.dto.DeviceDTO;


public interface DeviceResourceService {
    Device searchDevice(DeviceDTO deviceDTO);
}
```

DeviceResourceServiceImpl class

```
package ai.govi.telemetry.service;

import ai.govi.telemetry.domain.Device;
import ai.govi.telemetry.dto.DeviceDTO;
import ai.govi.telemetry.infrastructure.data.DeviceRepository;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Predicate;


public class DeviceResourceServiceImpl implements DeviceResourceService {

    private final DeviceRepository deviceRepository;

    private DeviceResourceServiceImpl(DeviceRepository deviceRepository) {
        this.deviceRepository = deviceRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Device searchDevice(DeviceDTO deviceDTO) {
       
        Device device = null;

        Integer id=deviceDTO.getDeviceId();
        String deviceRef=deviceDTO.getDeviceName();
        String deviceAlias=deviceDTO.getDeviceAlias();
        Date createdAt=deviceDTO.getCreatedAt();
        Date updatedAt=deviceDTO.getUpdatedAt();
        Map<String, String> metadata=deviceDTO.getMetadata();


        Predicate<Device> byDeviceId= id!=null ? data -> data.getDeviceId().equals(id): data -> true;
        Predicate<Device> byDeviceName= deviceRef!=null ? data -> data.getDeviceName().equals(deviceRef): data -> true;
        Predicate<Device> byDeviceAlias= deviceAlias!=null ? data -> data.getDeviceAlias().equals(deviceAlias): data -> true;
        Predicate<Device> byCreatedDate= createdAt!=null ? data -> data.getCreatedAt().equals(createdAt): data -> true;
        Predicate<Device> byUpdatedDate= updatedAt!=null ? data -> data.getUpdatedAt().equals(updatedAt): data -> true;
        Predicate<Device> byMetaData= metadata!=null ? data -> data.getMetadata().equals(metadata): data -> true;

      device = (Device) deviceRepository
                       .listAll()
                       .stream()
                       .filter(byDeviceId)
                       .filter(byDeviceName)
                       .filter(byDeviceAlias)
                       .filter(byCreatedDate)
                       .filter(byUpdatedDate)
                       .filter(byMetaData);

      return device;


    }


}
```

Endpoint created in DeviceResource class

```
 @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("device/{search}")
    @Operation(summary = "View a device by any attribute")
    public  Response searchDevice(@RequestBody DeviceDTO deviceDTO) {
        Log.info("GET: /apis/devices/device/:search : get device with any attribute: " );
        Device device=this.deviceResourceService.searchDevice(deviceDTO);
        return Response.ok(device).build();
    }
```

Can someone help me with this issue?Thank you in advance!

Comment: `@ApplicationScope` on `DeviceResourceServiceImpl` (or a `@Produces` method for type `DeviceResourceService`)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a scope for your bean.

```
@ApplicationScoped
DeviceResourceServerImpl implements DeviceResourceService {
```

or

```
@Singleton
DeviceResourceServerImpl implements DeviceResourceService {
```